# MySQL ExecuteNonQuery throws "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first" Exception

Tags: c#, mysql

I have multiple processes inserting data to the same table in my database. I am using one database connection for all the processes. When I was trying to run one of the sqlcommand, I got the above exception. I did some researching online and it seems that Mysql server only support one datareader per connection. And since each processes uses executeNonQuery to execute SQL commands in a fast speed, it is possible that the previous datareader was not closed when a new commands get issued.

Is there a way around this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The root cause of your error is that (hoping to avoid the obvious), the same connection is being used, and already open/executing. Are they `static` at the moment? Suggest looking into why the pooling isn't being used or is being limited.

Consider refactoring your code to have `using` statements. Pseudo, noncompiling example:

```
private void ExecNonQuery(string sqlStatement)
{          
    using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
    {
       using (var cmd = new MySqlDataCommand(conn))
       {
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(sqlStatement);
       }
    }
}
```

or

```
private List<Customer> GetCustomers( )
{
    string sqlStatement = "SELECT ID, Name FROM Customer";                
    using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
    {
        using (var cmd = new MySqlDataCommand(conn))
        {
           //get a reader and do something
           using (var reader = new MySqlDataReader(sqlStatement))
           { 
               ...
           }
        }
    }
}
```

By wrapping the creation of those objects in a `using` statement, you'll be ensuring that your objects are closed and disposed of properly.

I'd suggest that yes, you should be opening a new connection everytime. The [ADO.NET Driver for MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) **should** use proper connection pooling. You really shouldn't have to think about it.

Why have multiple processes share the same connection? What's the need there?

Comment: Does this requires to open a new connection every time I try to run a sql command? I have multiple processes sharing a same connection. Thanks.

Comment: each process receving data from socket interfaces and storing to database. The data come in from socket interface in a very fast speed sometimes.

Comment: Do you think BeginExecuteNonQuery will help?

Comment: @user: I'd suggest refactoring with `using` and see if it helps. Avoid any `static` as well.